# How to disable validation while opening dialog box on edit mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

when trying to open dialog in edit mode, validation message pop up with required message. but what i need to achieve is that when opening dialog box on edit mode as text box will contain value as soon as dialog box opens but then also validation message is there. how to remove that if already a value present in text box.

Example below for HTML code how I am using it.

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-6" show-errors>
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" ng-model="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" style="width: 74%;" required>
    <p class="help-block" ng-if="EditUserUserform.firstName.$error.required">Required</p>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-6" show-errors>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" ng-model="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" style="width: 74%;" required>
<p class="help-block" ng-if="EditUserUserform.lastName.$error.required">Required</p>
</div>
```

```js
app.directive('showErrors', function() {
 return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require:  '^form',
      link: function (scope, el, attrs, formCtrl) {
        // find the text box element, which has the 'name' attribute
        var inputEl   = el[0].querySelector("[name]");
        // convert the native text box element to an angular element
        var inputNgEl = angular.element(inputEl);
        // get the name on the text box so we know the property to check
        // on the form controller
        var inputName = inputNgEl.attr('name');

        // only apply the has-error class after the user leaves the text box
        inputNgEl.bind('blur', function() {
          el.toggleClass('has-error', formCtrl[inputName].$invalid);
        });
      }
    }
});
```

Below is the image when i am opening form in normal mode.

[image]

And below image shows when i open in edit mode.

[image]

the value already present in it but as soon as dialog opens it show validation message.

Comment: app.directive('showErrors', function(e) {e.preventDefault();} Please try, I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply but its not working

Answer (score 1):

I don't know angular at all and this is assuming you have access to the context of whether this is in edit mode or not, but it looks like you could do something here:

```
    inputNgEl.bind('blur', function() {
      //only check if not edit mode
      if (!edit) {
        el.toggleClass('has-error', formCtrl[inputName].$invalid);
      }
    });
```

unless angular has its own hooks to achieve the same thing, I'd say you could do it doing something like that.

Comment: i'm curious, is there a way to check for edit state at this point in the code? Alternatively, in edit mode you could give the inputs an extra style. For example `in-edit` then in your styles you can override the error styles with something like `.in-edit.has-error { background: <whatever the normal stuff is> }`

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if an input field hasn't been touched, the field's value didn't be filled by a user but by using controller , the `$pristine` will be `true`. So, you could fix this by firstly verifying the `$pristine` value:

```
    // only apply the has-error class after the user leaves the text box
    inputNgEl.bind('blur', function() {
      // Only do this if and only if the field has been touched and the value is invalid
      el.toggleClass('has-error', !formCtrl[inputName].$pristine && formCtrl[inputName].$invalid);
    });
```

Alternatively, you could use `$dirty` value which will be `false` if the field hasn't been touched.

```
      el.toggleClass('has-error', formCtrl[inputName].$dirty && formCtrl[inputName].$invalid);
```